# Does the storage limit (on IndexedDB or localStorage) apply for local apps running off the computer?

Tags: html, google-chrome, local-storage, indexeddb, web-sql

If I write a web app that will run in Chrome or Firefox and uses IndexedDB (or localStorage), but it's not hosted anywhere and instead is run by the user double-clicking a local ".html" file, will the limits on storage size still apply?

I'm referring to this:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#unlimited

> [Unlimited Storage is] unique to Chrome extensions as well as hosted and installed web apps.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not hosted, indexeddb won't work. The indexeddb is [origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dependencies) dependend, meaning it needs to have an address. Local file system doesn't meet that requirement.

Webapps are a different story, but these apps need to be installed and run inside a sandbox.